# Hashing : Insertion to a Deleted Slot 

Tags: hash

I'm new to hashing and here's my question:

Can you insert in a DELETED slot of the hash table?

Comment: Yes, but which language do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can insert to a deleted slot. But...

At first you should know that there is soft-deletion and hard-deletion. In soft-delete you just flip a flag and mark your slot as "deleted", in hard-delete you empty the slot.

Let me explain why we need soft-delete: For example you're using a hash table with linear probing and somehow your hash function maps 3 input values to the same slot. By using linear probing you place these three elements by advancing linearly on the table until you find an empty slot. In this case if you use hard-delete for deletion, you will break the hash table since there will be an empty slot while try to retrieve a value so one value will become unreachable.

On the other hand; if you have a perfect hash function you are OK to use hard-delete. A perfect hash function maps every input value to slots uniquely. So no probing scheme is needed and hard-delete doesn't break your table.

Now coming back to your question, you should also consider and figure out how to avoid duplicate insertions.